# Building a carousel to slide items by 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm currently building a slider/carousel that could slide items by 4 instead of 1. I managed to make it slide 1 by 1 and append the first element to the last and vice versa by clicking the next and prev buttons. How can I make my carousel slide by 4. I would prefer not to use bootstrap.

https://jsfiddle.net/clestcruz/jhz09efj/4/

Here is the code that i'm currently working on

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class='carousel -aim-partners'>

        <div class='item-list'>
            <ul>
              <li>1</li>
              <li>2</li>
              <li>3</li>
              <li>4</li>
              <li>5</li>
              <li>6</li>
              <li>7</li>
              <li>8</li>
              <li>9</li>
              <li>10</li>
              <li>11</li>
              <li>12</li>
              <li>13</li>
              <li>14</li>
              <li>15</li>
              <li>16</li>             

            </ul>
        </div>


        <ul class="btns">
            <li class="prev">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true">prev</i>
            </li>
            <li class="next">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true">next</i>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.carousel {
    position : relative;

    .item-list {
        overflow : hidden;

        ul {
            display       : flex;
            flex-wrap     : wrap;
            list-style    : none;
            margin-bottom : 10px;
            position      : relative;
            left          : -257px;
            overflow      : hidden;


        }

    }

    .btns {
        width    : 100%;
        z-index  : 10;
        top      : 50%;

        @extend .columns;
        @extend .-items-center;
        @extend .-space-between;

        li {
            display : inline-block;
            cursor  : pointer;
        }
    }



    &.-aim-partners {
        position : relative;

        .item-list {
            max-width : 1204px;
            margin    : 0 auto;
        }

        .item-list ul li {
            flex              : 0 230px;
            width             : 300px;  
            padding           : 0px;
            height            : 110px;
            margin-top        : 10px;
            margin-bottom     : 10px; 
            margin-left       : 5px; 
            margin-right      : 5px;  
            background-size   : contain;
            background-repeat : no-repeat;
            background-position : center;

        }

        .btns {
            width : 110%;
            left  : -70px;

            li {
                width  : 35px;
                height : 40px;

                &.prev {
                    background : url('../images/carousel-icon-arrow.png') no-repeat 15px 0;
                }

                &.next {
                    background : url('../images/carousel-icon-arrow.png') no-repeat -20px 0;
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

---

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    var carousel = {


        init : function() {


            var carouselWidth = 0;

            // Set Container Width
            $('.carousel .item-list ul').children().each(function() {
                carouselWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
                $('.carousel .item-list ul').width(carouselWidth + 1000);
            });

            //Click to Slide Right
            $('.btns .next').click(function(){

                var itemWidth = $('.carousel .item-list ul li').outerWidth() + 10;
                var leftIndent = parseInt($('.carousel .item-list ul').css('left')) - itemWidth;

                $('.carousel .item-list ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : leftIndent}, 500,function(){    
                    $('.carousel .item-list ul').append($('.carousel .item-list ul li:first')); 
                    $('.carousel .item-list ul').css({'left' : '-' + itemWidth + 'px'});
                }); 
            });

            //Click to Slide Left
            $('.btns .prev').click(function(){

                var itemWidth = $('.carousel .item-list ul li').outerWidth() + 10;
                var leftIndent = parseInt($('.carousel .item-list ul').css('left')) + itemWidth;

                $('.carousel .item-list ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : leftIndent}, 500,function(){    
                    $('.carousel .item-list ul').prepend($('.carousel .item-list ul li:last'));                  
                    $('.carousel .item-list ul').css({'left' : '-' + itemWidth + 'px'});
                });


            });


        }

    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        carousel.init();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You coud use this jquery plugin https://github.com/gibbok/jquery-slidertv (disclaimer: I am the owner of the project)

Comment: I prefer not to use a third party plugin to achieve what I'm building. Would like to learn how to build it instead :)

Comment: Is the width of the the items fixed and equal to each other or is it dynamic ?

Comment: The width of each element is fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**: Your updated code and a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/upqk8nkn/) example.

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    var carousel = {

        init : function() {

            var carouselWidth = 0;

            // Set Container Width
            $('.carousel .item-list ul').children().each(function() {
                carouselWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
                $('.carousel .item-list ul').width(carouselWidth + 1000);
            });

            $('.btns .next').click(function(){

                var itemWidth = $('.carousel .item-list ul li').outerWidth() + 10;
                var leftIndent = parseInt($('.carousel .item-list ul').css('left')) - itemWidth;

                function animate( repeat, speed ) {
                    $('.carousel .item-list ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : leftIndent}, speed,function(){
                        $('.carousel .item-list ul').append( $('.carousel .item-list ul li:first') );
                        $('.carousel .item-list ul').css({'left' : '-' + itemWidth + 'px'});

                        if ( repeat > 1 ) {
                            animate( ( repeat - 1 ), speed );
                        }
                    });
                }

                animate( 4, 100 );

            });

            $('.btns .prev').click(function() {

                var itemWidth = $('.carousel .item-list ul li').outerWidth() + 10;
                var leftIndent = parseInt($('.carousel .item-list ul').css('left')) + itemWidth;

                function animate( repeat, speed ) {
                    $('.carousel .item-list ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : leftIndent}, speed,function(){
                        $('.carousel .item-list ul').prepend($('.carousel .item-list ul li:last'));
                        $('.carousel .item-list ul').css({'left' : '-' + itemWidth + 'px'});

                        if ( repeat > 1 ) {
                            animate( ( repeat - 1 ), speed );
                        }
                    });
                }

                animate( 4, 100 );

            });

        }

    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        carousel.init();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: The only issue I found in your solution is when you click the `prev` the slider must finishing sliding the before the items could render or appear. The `next` has no issues

Comment: Please see the updated code. Is the code producing the desired behavior?

Comment: The result is still the same on the `previous` button, kindly check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/clestcruz/jhz09efj/18/

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Question though what does the `(times)` do in the function

Comment: Updated the code so it's more user friendly. When calling the animate function, the first argument is for the number of times you want to repeat the animation (i.e. the number of times you want to move previous or next). The second argument is for the animation speed. Let me know if you have any additional questions.